# Concurrent collection enumerator

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently programming my own implementation of priority queue / sorted list and I would like to have it concurrent.
In order to have it thread safe I'm using `lock(someObject)` and I would like to verify some behavior of mutexes in C#.

Inner representation of my sorted list is basically linked list with `head` and slots linked together.
Something like:

```
internal class Slot
{
    internal T Value;
    internal Slot Next;

    public Slot(T value, Slot next = null)
    {
        Value = value;
        Next = next;
    }
}
```

Every time I'm manipulating with `head` I have to use `lock(someObject)`because of thread safety.
In order to implement `ICollection` interface I have to implement `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`. In this method I have take my `head` and read from it so I should use mutex.

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (syncLock)
    {
        var curr = head;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            yield return curr.Value;
            curr = curr.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Is `syncLock` locked for whole time in enumerator (so it will be unlocked after reaching end of the method) or it is automatically unlocked after yielding value?

Comment: It will be locked for the entire duration of the enumeration - hence, it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @Matthew Watson thank you, so it would be better to unlock it before `yield return curr.Value` and afterwards lock it again, right?

                `Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
                yield return valueToReturn;
                Monitor.Enter(syncLock);`

Comment: Can you leverage on any of the collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent` eg. `BlockingCollection`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: Because you lock without the loop, it will indeed persist between yields. I assume you're doing this as an exercise otherwise you should use the BCL facilities.

Comment: To be honest - it's not a very good idea to make priority queue "concurrent" like this. Just leave it non-thread safe and let its user decide when and how to lock, if it's being used from multiple threads. But if you insist - obtain a lock, create a copy of all items, release lock, then return that copy to the caller of `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: Does it need to be able to return an Enumerator? How do you use it?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer because it should implement `ICollection` interface and thus implement `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @Evk thanks, I will probably go with copying elements and returning iterator of new collection.

Comment: @Delfi True, but you can just throw a not supported exception in that method. From the looks of it it would be a very bad idea to enumerate the entire queue if it's locked.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yup, that is probably bad idea to lock it, so I will probably just copy elements to the new collection and return enumerator of that new collection.

Or there is still possibility to add `Note that this collection is not thread safe` to the documentation, but still... I would like to avoid that note,

Comment: @Delfi Or do what `List` does: Allow enumeration but throw a collection modified exception of it was changed during enumeration. While returning a copy would make it work - whoever uses your class might not be aware of this behavior (which can lead to bugs that are hard to track).

Comment: Note that locking within the loop will basically do nothing, so it's not worth it.

Comment: Another approach is to make an immutable collection. Once you have an immutable object, concurrency problems tend to go away.

Comment: What will your functionality provide that isn't natively provided by `ConcurrentQueue` or `BlockingCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys from the comments, here's sum up.

Answer: yes, `syncLock` will be locked for the whole time → hence, it's a really bad idea

Possible solution:

- make collection not thread safe
- obtain lock, copy whole collection and return enumerator of this collection @Evk
- use some kind of boolean flag, set it on `true` while enumerating over the collection and throw exception when `Add`, `Clear` or `Remove` methods are called -> this is default `List` behavior @ManfredRadlwimmer
- make that collection immutable @InBetween

Comment: You have one more approach to consider: make an immutable collection.